# Creating MSK topic using python script and boto3

Tags: python, boto3, aws-msk

I want to develop a python script to create topics in MSK using AWS SDK boto3. I don't see any methods to create a topic in Kafka.client. I can use kafka-python but wanted to use AWS SDK or CDK

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon MSK APIs are meant for operations for managing an Amazon MSK cluster. For operations with Apache Zookeeper or Apache Kafka you can use kafka-python or execute Kafka/Zookeeper APIs from a jumpbox to MSK brokers directly.